# NEXUS card proof of citizenship for passport renewal?

Tags: passport-renewals, identity-cards, nexus, trusted-traveler

I need to renew my US passport card in-person. I applied to renew my passport book and card by mail, but I had lost my previous passport card (many years ago) and had forgotten that I had one. The State Department rejected my application, sending me a letter saying I need to take the letter to a passport acceptance facility within 90 days to complete the application. However, the State Department kept my passport book. Therefore, the only proof of citizenship I have in my possession is my NEXUS card; I do not have my birth certificate. (I was born in the US.)

Is a NEXUS card that says “Citizenship: USA” proof of citizenship for purposes of applying for a new passport?

It of course is valid as proof of identity and citizenship for international travel (with limitations not relevant here), and lists the issuing country as USA and my citizenship as USA. It is not listed as one of the documents on the state department web site or the form DS-11 instructions, but I'm not sure what else I'm supposed to do since they didn't return my passport book. (I also have separate documents that can establish identity but not citizenship which have passport-quality photos instead of the webcam photo that is weirdly used on the NEXUS card.)

(Having a passport card is not crucial for me, since I normally use the NEXUS card and also will have the new passport book, but I like having the extra wallet-sized border crossing document and proof of citizenship.)

Comment: I have a NEXUS card. I'm Canadian. So no, it's not proof of US citizenship.

Comment: It's the fact that it's a NEXUS card that says "Citizenship: USA" that makes me think it *ought* to be proof of US citizenship. Obviously a NEXUS card that says "Citizenship: Canada" would not be proof of US citizenship.

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question in a limited fashion based on experience:

I went to the US post office to complete my DS-11 application for a replacement passport card. I asked the postal clerk if the NEXUS card is acceptable proof of identity and citizenship for this purpose. She said, without hesitation, yes.

However, I did not truly test this, as I had in the interim found my birth certificate. I was not willing to mail my NEXUS card to the State Department, as it's the only border crossing ID in my possession and I will be crossing multiple times in the next few weeks, so I can't verify that the State Department itself would have agreed with the postal clerk's interpretation. Instead, I mailed the birth certificate.

Comment: Following up: after many months, neither my new passport card nor my birth certificate ever arrived in the mail. The State Department has no idea if they sent them but says it's been more than 90 days since they sent them (a rather obvious contradiction, to my eye!), so I can't apply for a replacement but instead need to start the whole process over again (starting with replacing the birth certificate they or the postal service lost). Glad I didn't send the NEXUS card!

Answer (score 1):

> Is the NEXUS card proof of citizenship for purposes of applying for a new passport?

No. Foreign citizens can get a NEXUS card as well. See [here](https://ttp.dhs.gov/):

> Eligibility
>
> U.S. citizens, U.S. lawful permanent residents, Canadian citizens, Canadian permanent residents, and Mexican nationals

You have to provide proof of citizenship to the Department's satisfaction (see the instructions to the form DS-11). The department will not be satisfied with the Nexus card since it is not on the list of the documents that would satisfy it, as you've noted.

Why can't you get your birth certificate? AFAIK you can get a certified copy from the county where you were born any time.

Comment: I couldn't reliably get a new birth certificate (California, in my case) and then drive to the US to a passport acceptance facility (post office) within the 90 day timeframe the State Department gave me; I certainly couldn't do that and get my new passport back in time for my next passport-requiring trip given 8-11 week current processing time (mailed passport in 2 months ago already). However, fortunately, this became moot for me since I finally found my birth certificate. But still appreciate having the answer!

Comment: (Not clear to me why the fact that foreign citizens can get a NEXUS card means one that says "Citizenship: USA" is not proof of US citizenship, since the ID requirements to get one that says "Citizenship: USA" were the same as getting a passport.)

Comment: @AlexHill The NEXUS card on its own is not a proof of anything, it's tied to the NEXUS system which is a CBP system, not a DOS. It is not an official government ID that is recognized by the DoS as a proof of citizenship or identity. It may also show "citizenship: Canada", and you may still be a US citizen. I live in Caifornia, I was able to get certified copies of vital records from my county on the spot, why is 90 days not enough for you?

Comment: The web site says 5-7 weeks turnaround for birth certificate requests. Then 3 weeks (not kidding, that's my recent experience) for normal mail US to Canada (no expedite option). Then need time to drive to the US (or my nearest Consulate, which is a 5 hour drive away, much further than the border) on a weekday when there's an appointment.

A birth certificate isn't DOS either, and my 40-year-old piece of paper would be *far* easier to forge than a NEXUS card!

If it said "citizenship: Canada", obviously wouldn't be proof (even if dual citizen). But mine doesn't. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlexHill I'm sure as an American you appreciate the American system of "no formal ids allowed ever anywhere unless we want to discriminate someone" now :-) As a foreigner I'm always entertained to watch Americans create problems for themselves and then complain that it makes their lives difficult. If only they had some kind of national ids system like any other normal country does :-D

Comment: The Nexus card is not a DoS document, but many other acceptable documents are not DoS documents, including some issued by DHS such as the naturalization certificate and citizenship certificate.  It would perhaps be reasonable for the DoS to add Nexus cards to the list; they just haven't done so. @AlexHill getting a birth certificate shouldn't take more than a couple of days in person or a couple of weeks by mail.  Driving to a post office shouldn't take more than a few minutes in most of the country.  The State Department pads their estimates; you'll probably get it in 3 or 4 weeks.

Comment: @AlexHill, when you are at the passport facility, please ask if your NEXUS card is acceptable and come back here to post your answer.

Comment: @littleadv You won’t see me defending pretty much any aspect of the US approach to IDs, as I have let my Congresswoman know several times! America manages to simultaneously require IDs where requiring IDs is absurd, not require IDs where they should be required, *and* make it reasonably onerous to get an ID to make them tools for discrimination!

Comment: @phoog I don’t live in the US. My options are a five hour drive (each way, so a full day with likely an overnight given very limited appointment availability) to the nearest consulate or a three hour drive across the border to the nearest US post office. The nearby county (Okanogan County, WA) is larger than Rhode Island and has one post office that does passports, so definitely not a few minute drive for most in that county. It was six weeks from when they received my application to processing and rejecting it.

Comment: @Willeke I will definitely ask. Since I’ve found my birth certificate, I won’t send it off with the NEXUS card only since it’s up to the State Department, not the clerk at the post office, to make the actual decision, much as I’d like to run the experiment. (I truly wish I sensibly could!)

Comment: "Why can't you get your birth certificate?" I, for example, don't have one. I have a "Certificate of Birth Abroad" issued by the State Department because I was born in a W. German hospital to American parents (my dad was in the Army at the time). Neither of my parents could come up with a copy, and it took a while to A) track down the process for finding out what this document was, and B) applying for a copy and waiting for State to process it. Took about 4-6 months if I recall. Not everyone can pop down to the local shop to get a copy...

Comment: @FreeMan you go through it once and then you know, right? It's not that all of a sudden you discover two days before you need to renew the passport that you need to do all this, you've done it already.

Comment: True, for a renewal. However, it took quite a bit of digging to get this in order to apply for the passport in the first place.

Comment: Note that a Consular Report of Birth Abroad (presumably that's what you have, @FreeMan) is on the list of approved documents (like a US birth certificate). But same difference: if you don't have it, it's not trivial for everyone to find a new one, and the fact that a NEXUS card that says "Citizenship: USA" is even slightly questionable as proof of citizenship is just weird.